# MongoDB Tag-Aware Sharding Workflow

Tags: performance, mongodb, sharding

I wonder the work flow of sharding cluster in Tag-Aware Sharding.

```
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 3,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
    "currentVersion" : 4,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("546df06d63a15917a8356f4e")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "hadoop4:27017",  "tags" : [  "TR" ] }
    {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "hadoop5:27018",  "tags" : [  "US" ] }
    {  "_id" : "shard0002",  "host" : "hadoop6:27017",  "tags" : [  "OTHER" ] }

  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "inventory",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
```

In tag-aware sharding , with mongorestore command via mongos , first all data writes to PrimaryDatabase and then migrate the appropriate chunks ?

Or it can fill the appropriate chunk according to tagRange at the beggining of the insert?

For example , when i insert {country:"US",keyword:"abc"} document , at first it goes to shard0001 or goes to the primary database shard0000  and then chunk migration to shard0001?

Comment: Please share your shard key

Comment: My shard key is {country:1,keyword:1} @Antonis

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the distribution of your inserts if moves going to occur and how many.

1) you start with one chunk {minkey,maxkey} which lives on primary (lets say shard000)

2) as you insert data a split will occur. Might be

2.1) {minkey, US} {US,maxkey} -> moves the second chunk to shar001

2.2) {minkey, TR} {TR,maxkey} -> moves first chunk to shard001

2.3) {minkey,OTHER} {OTHER,maxkey} -> moves second shard to shard002

3) I cant analyze all paths but for 2.1)

{US,maxkey} is unmovable and all the chunks come from it as well

{minkey, US} depends if it going to move according to the next split

....